# Node JS communicating through sockets

Tags: html, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to play around with sockets. I created a web server in node:

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
console.log("server has been created");
res.writeHead(200,{"Content-type:": "text/plain"});
res.end("Welcome to my supa' nodejs app");

}).listen(1337);

console.log("Server running at 127.0.0.1:1337");



 var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
 io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
    socket.on("input_written",function(){
        console.log("someone clicked the button");
    });


 });
```

I also have a html file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Home page</title>


    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
                    var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:1337");
            function clickedButton()
            {


            socket.on("connect",function(){
                socket.emit("input_written");
            });


            }
        </script>
        <button type="button" onclick="clickedButton()">Click me</button>


    </body>

</html>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when I press that button my console logs "someone clicked the button". However at the moment nothing happens. I'm not sure what I'm missing

**UPDATE**
As @Zub recommended I added

```
console.log("clicked");
```

right before the socket.emit();
I checked the console and this is the output:

```
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined (index):11
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined
```

Comment: I would recommend to initialize client io connection beyond `clickedButton` function, because you surely don't want to establish new connection on each button click. Also try to write `console.log('clicked');` right before `socket.emit("input_written");`. Does browser console outputs 'clicked' when you click the button?

Comment: you should remove `socket.on("connect"...` form that function as well. Leave just `socket.emit("input_written");` otherwise it will not work

Comment: @Zub that did the trick. Modify your answer and I will accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you bind node server on 1337, you have to point that port when you load `socket.io.js` script.

So try to replace

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="http://localhost:1337/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

**Edit**

You should also initialize client socket.io connection beyond `clickedButton` function and leave just `socket.emit("input_written");` in it.

Answer (score 0):

The url in your browser needs to match the socket connection url. You have localhost in your io.connect, so make sure the url in your browser reads `http://localhost/`. If you connect to `http://127.0.0.1/` in your browser then it won't work.

Comment: My browser is pointed towards localhost and it doesn't log "button clicked"